# Div Ignore max-width on body

Tags: html, css, width

I've set a max-width on my body but I want one div to not have this max-width but have a full-width.

HTML

```
<body>
<header> stuff here </header>
<main> 
more stuff

<div> The div I want to have a full-width </div>
</main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    body {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
          }

div { ?}
```

Comment: You question is quite unclear. Please care enough to provide some information on what actually is your problem. Divs usually have 100% width by default, so the full width in this case will be 1200px as defined for the body.

Comment: Oh sorry, I want the div to have full width. So if the screen is 1600px, the body will be 1200px. So I want the div to have 1600px width then

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the div at a full width, you must have it outside the body.

```
   <body>
   <header> stuff here </header>
   <main> 
    more stuff


   </main>
   </body>
   <div> The div I want to have a full-width </div>
```

and css:

```
 div{width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position as `absolute` to make the DIV get out of the body. Then set the width to 100% which will match the screen size.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc8Lgcdh/) for example.